# canvas.toDataURL() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, qr-code

I'm trying to download a generated QRCode from the `react-qr-code` library but I'm stuck at the step of actually downloading the image.

```js
import QRCode from "react-qr-code";
```

I generate the QRCode inside my React component like so:

```js
return(
.
.
.
    <QRCode id="qrcode" level="H" value={box.id} size={100} />
    <Button onClick={downloadQRCode}>Download QR</Button>
);
```

my download function:

```js
 const downloadQRCode = () => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("qrcode") as HTMLCanvasElement;
    if (!canvas) throw new Error("Canvas not found");
    const pngUrl = canvas
      .toDataURL("image/png")
      .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = pngUrl;
    downloadLink.download = `${box.id}.png`;
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  };
```

if I `console.log(canvas)` before trying to `toDataURL` it's got the correct svg.
However, when I run the `downloadQRCode` function all I get is:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toDataURL is not a function
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you're trying to use native DOM methods in a React application. Look into using a ref to identify the canvas, and then something like `const canvas = ref.current; const url = canvas.toDataURL()`.

Comment: Who says the QRCode is actually a canvas and not a wrapper with a canvas in it? It also looks (at a glance) that that plugin uses SVG - which is _not_ a canvas, and needs to be rendered into a canvas by drawing it (or an image tag referring to it) into another canvas altogether. In short, this error makes sense because you are not working with a canvas in all likelihood.

Comment: [If this is the same library](https://github.com/zpao/qrcode.react) then it also looks like `<QRCode>` is deprecated, and you should be using `<QRCodeCanvas>` (or `<QRCodeSVG>`. Note there are [_actual examples_ on how to use this library](https://github.com/zpao/qrcode.react/blob/trunk/examples/download.tsx) which you might want to look at.

Comment: I just solved this in vue. The canvas was inside #qrcode, not #qrcode itself.

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere  and @Andy for the help! The issue was that it was an SVG from the start. Using the `QRCodeCanvas` from a better library fixed it all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by switching the library from `react-qr-code`, which doesn't seem to the best library for this to `qrcode.react`.

This lets me use `<QRCodeCanvas/>` and `<QRCodeSVG/>` elements.

Using the `QRCodeCanvas` like was suggested in the comments solved this issue.

```js
<QRCodeCanvas id="qrcode" level="H" value={box.id} size={100} />
<Button onClick={downloadQRCode}>Download QR</Button>
```